# How to solve error: cannot find symbol class RequestFinishedListener

Tags: android, request, android-volley

In my project i'm using volley package. But it shows cannot find symbol class newRequestQueue in Volley. How can I solve it.

And I'm already import the volley package

```
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener;
```

This is my source code

```
queue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
        // Start NewActivity.class
        Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(NewActivity.this, New2Activity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent1);
        Log.e("Error Response 2", "Request Finish");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the line below to your app level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

And then this is the workable code

```
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    queue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestFinished(Request<Object> request) {
            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityTwo.class);
            startActivity(myIntent1);
            Log.e("Error Response 2", "Request Finish");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Same error "error: cannot find symbol class RequestFinishedListener"

Comment: "import com.android.volley.RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener" you should delete this line.

Comment: "import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;" only import this 3 line.

Comment: sorry then. on my end, the code works perfectly fine.